# Does cups work the same for Raspbian and Ubuntu?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, printing

Can a ppd file work for Ubuntu and Raspbian Os? Are the ppd files os dependent?
Using the same ppd file for TSC on Raspbian gives an error "**/usr/libexec/cups/filter/rastertospl failed**". However selecting a Samsung printer for printing works on raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

PPD files are platform-independent. However, they may reference external executables, and those are platform-dependent. In particular, [`cupsFilter`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-ppd.html#cupsFilter) specifies a program that converts the input from a format that CUPS understands into a format that the printer understands. You'll need to find an ARM/Linux version of the filter program to use this PPD file under ARM/Linux (RasPi).

As a fallback, you could try to use a generic PPD file. Which you already appear to do.